# How to perform a function when value is assigned to an object member?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, appointment, with a member, time:

```
function appointment(date_string){
    this.time = ???;
}
```

When I get time from the database, it has trailing zeros. I'd like to remove them before assigning the value. For instance:

```
var a = new appointment("01/15/2015");
a.time = "01:33:00.000";
console.log(a.time) // should display 01:33:00, NOT 01:33:00.000
```

I tried

```
function appoinment(date_sting) {    
    this.time = function(){return (this.time).replace(".000","");};
}
```

but this does not work in the scenario.

Comment: And you can't do `a.time = "01:33:00.000".replace( ".000", "" );`?

Comment: I can, but I don't want to do that every time I assign a value. It should happen automatically so a.time = "01:33:00.000" will automatically become "01:33:00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [ES 5.1 (ECMA 262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) you can use the `set` operator with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

```
function appointment() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'time', {
        set: function (value) {
            value = value + '';
            this._time = value.replace(".000","");
        },
        get: function () {
            return this._time;
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Update**

I came up with a better version that does not pollute `this`' scope:

```
function appointment() {
    var time;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'time', {
        set: function (value) {
            value = value + '';
            time = value.replace(".000","");
        },
        get: function () {
            return time;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "too much recursion" error: PUT THIS IN YOUR CONSOLE TO TEST:        function appointment() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'time', {
        set: function (value) {
            value = value + '';
          this.time = value.replace(":00.0000000","");
        }
    });
}

var a = new appointment();

a.time = "15:33:00.0000000";

a.time

Comment: @Travis For the record, it wasn't adding the `get` that did it by itself, initially the setter was calling `this.time = ....` which is just calling itself.  The updated version uses a different variable to hold the actual value.  Personally I would use a variable local to the `appointment` function/object, as at the moment it's still possible to change the value using `a._time = ...`

Comment: Which has now been added :)

Comment: JSYK, the value being returned by the setter function does nothing. :-)

Comment: Yes I saw that, I'll remove it :)

Comment: So looking at the Mozilla specs, am I to believe this won't work for IE before 9? I need IE 8 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your best friend. :)

```
a.time = "01:33:00.000".replace(/\.0+$/, "");
```

Also, the reason why "01:33:00.000".replace(".000") isn't doing anything is probably because you've forgotten to specify the second argument of the replace method: the string that replaces the first:

```
a.time = "01:33:00.000".replace(".000", "");
```

I recommend using a regex though, since it resolves the issue of having varying numbers of trailing zeroes. :)

**EDIT:** Okay, I see what you're trying to achieve now; you want something that dynamically parses the value upon assignment. In this situation, you'd want to use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var Appointment = function(timeString){
    var _time;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "time", {
        get:    function(){ return _time; },
        set:    function(i){
            _time = (i || "").replace(/\.0+$/, "");
        }
    });

    this.time = timeString;
};

console.log(new Appointment("20/08/2015").time);
```

Fair warning though, using Object.defineProperty on *native JavaScript objects* isn't going to work on Internet Explorer 8. So this approach comes down to which browsers you're willing to support.

If supporting IE8 (and/or older) is a concern, I'd suggest resorting to using old-school get/set functions instead:

```
var Appointment = function(timeString){
    var _time;

    this.setTime    =   function(i){
        _time = (i || "").replace(/\.0+$/, "");
    };
    this.getTime    =   function(i){
        return _time;
    };
    this.setTime(timeString);
};

console.log(new Appointment("20/08/2015 1:33:00.000").getTime());
```

Comment: I don't want to have to write that every time I assign a value. I'd like it to perform automatically when time is assigned.

Comment: Well... yes, you'd have that regular expression run inside the body of the constructor. :) Add it where the value is being assigned to the instance's "time" property.

Comment: Done... I see somebody else beat me to the punch while I was typing/testing, though. xD